# Unable to load asset: error when loading an .mp3 file Flutter

Tags: flutter, assets

I'm adding sounds to my app using the `audioplayers` package but at first build no sound is played. After a Hot-restart dough when loading the file I get this exception:

```
E/flutter (32175): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/assets/click.mp3
E/flutter (32175): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
E/flutter (32175): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (32175): #1      AudioCache._fetchAsset (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:60:29)
E/flutter (32175): #2      AudioCache.fetchToMemory (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:67:30)
E/flutter (32175): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (32175): #3      AudioCache.load (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:82:37)
E/flutter (32175): #4      AudioCache.getAbsoluteUrl (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:140:23)
E/flutter (32175): #5      AudioCache.play (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:103:24)
E/flutter (32175): #6      _MapScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:fixit_cloud_biking/Screens/map_screen.dart:1239:46)
E/flutter (32175): #7      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:706:14)
E/flutter (32175): #8      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:789:36)
E/flutter (32175): #9      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter (32175): #10     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:486:11)
E/flutter (32175): #11     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:264:5)
E/flutter (32175): #12     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:199:7)
E/flutter (32175): #13     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:467:9)
E/flutter (32175): #14     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:76:12)
E/flutter (32175): #15     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:117:9)
E/flutter (32175): #16     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379:8)
E/flutter (32175): #17     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:115:18)
E/flutter (32175): #18     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:7)
E/flutter (32175): #19     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:19)
E/flutter (32175): #20     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter (32175): #21     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (32175): #22     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter (32175): #23     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter (32175): #24     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1138:13)
E/flutter (32175): #25     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter (32175): #26     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
E/flutter (32175): #27     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:273:10)
E/flutter (32175): #28     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:5)
E/flutter (32175):
```

I did put the files in the same assets folder that contains all the images I use for the icons so indentation in `pubspec.yaml` file is correct.
The problem shouldn't be the file naming either as I use camel cased or single word naming(lesson learned from images naming with empty spaces..).
One thing though worth to mention is that if I drag and drop files onto the `assets`folder I get an error. I tried deleting the folder, recreating it and then drag and drop works, but only once.. files added in a second moment throw the error.
This is the button that should play the sound:

```
IconButton(
                        icon: Image.asset('assets/centerMapButton.png'),
                        iconSize: 60,
                        onPressed: () async {
                          await widget.cache.play('assets/click.mp3',
                              volume: 50, mode: PlayerMode.MEDIA_PLAYER);
                          print('Center map button pressed');
                          _mapController.move(userLocation, 16);
                        }),
```

and the `AudioCache()`is declared as `AudioCache cache = new AudioCache();`.

Comment: After adding  files for the second time have you restarted (by stopping and relaunching) your app

Comment: I tried both the app was running and when it wasn't. I did solve the file loading problem dough as it turns out that the path doesn't have to be specified as the plugin looks straight into the assets folder. `play('assets/click.mp3')` is wrong, `play('click.mp3') works as expected.. I did noticed from the error `Unable to load asset: assets/assets/click.mp3` that 'assets/' appeared twice, so I tried omitting it and it worked. Still I have to solve the drag and drop files adding problem, as copying them with finder works, but something is obviously wrong..

Comment: This  is really weird

Comment: yeap.. I'm gonna try moving the the project folder onto a different drive and see if makes any difference..

Comment: @Vincenzo That's actually by design. You can read the documentation here: https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/blob/master/doc/audio_cache.md

Comment: @MidhunMP indeed it't by design. I took for granted that I had to specify the path to the file also, but after I saw that it was working without I took a better look at docs and saw it.. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

This can happen in [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) if you don't set the assets location in **pubspec.yaml**.

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - audio/
```

This tells Flutter that you have an **audio** folder in the root of your project where you keep your audio assets.

After doing that, you should be able to set the asset and play it like so:

```
await player.setAsset('audio/cow.mp3');
player.play();
```

The error can also happen if you spelled something in the path wrong, but I assume you already checked for that.

Answer (score 3):

TRY CHANGING THIS
assets/click.mp3
TO
click.mp3

I had the same error neglecting the "assets/" in the path makes it play sounds from local seamlessly. Audioplayers assumes that its default path is assets/

Comment: Hi. Welcome and thanks for your answer. Fortunately I did discover that, and thanks to MidhumMP comment I saw why. Again thanks and welcome to the community.

Answer (score 2):

Clearing the assets folder worked for me :

```
await AudioPlayer.clearAssetCache();
```

> Clears the plugin's internal asset cache directory. Call this when
> the   app's assets have changed to force assets to be re-fetched from
> the asset   bundle.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in `assets` U don't need to write it .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you assets path is: lib/assets/audio/

and in your file pubspec.yaml

assets:
- lib/assets/audio/

```
class Sound {
  static final AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();

  static void playSound(int option){
    player.audioCache.prefix = 'lib/assets/audio/';
    player.setPlayerMode(PlayerMode.mediaPlayer);
    player.play(AssetSource('note$option.wav'), mode: PlayerMode.lowLatency);
    player.audioCache.clearAll();
  }
}
```