# Flutter Audioplayers Unable to load asset

Tags: android, ios, flutter, assets, flutter-dependencies

I am attempting to play a simple sound using flutter's audioplayers library. When I attempt to, I get an **Unable to load asset** error. I've gone through several related questions on this site, and all of them seem to only suggest checking the indentation on the **pubspec.yaml** file and running **flutter clean**. I have done this several times and have had no results. **Flutter Doctor** finds no issues.

When I click the button that should cause the sound to play, I receive this:

```
E/flutter (22727): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/sounds/start.mp3
E/flutter (22727): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
E/flutter (22727): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22727): #1      AudioCache._fetchAsset (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:60:29)
E/flutter (22727): #2      AudioCache.fetchToMemory (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:67:30)
E/flutter (22727): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22727): #3      AudioCache.load (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:82:37)
E/flutter (22727): #4      AudioCache.getAbsoluteUrl (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:140:23)
E/flutter (22727): #5      AudioCache.play (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:103:24)
E/flutter (22727): #6      playSound (package:tick_tok_bio/player.dart:14:20)
E/flutter (22727): #7      MapsState.startNewRoute (package:tick_tok_bio/gps_tracking.dart:122:13)
E/flutter (22727): #8      MapsState.startStop.<anonymous closure> (package:tick_tok_bio/gps_tracking.dart:240:13)
E/flutter (22727): #9      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:779:19)
E/flutter (22727): #10     _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:862:36)
E/flutter (22727): #11     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter (22727): #12     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:504:11)
E/flutter (22727): #13     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:282:5)
E/flutter (22727): #14     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:217:7)
E/flutter (22727): #15     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:475:9)
E/flutter (22727): #16     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:76:12)
E/flutter (22727): #17     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:9)
E/flutter (22727): #18     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379:8)
E/flutter (22727): #19     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:120:18)
E/flutter (22727): #20     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:106:7)
E/flutter (22727): #21     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:19)
E/flutter (22727): #22     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter (22727): #23     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (22727): #24     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter (22727): #25     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter (22727): #26     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1196:13)
E/flutter (22727): #27     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter (22727): #28     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:987:7)
E/flutter (22727): #29     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:275:10)
E/flutter (22727): #30     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:184:5)
```

Here is the code that should play the audio file:

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

AudioPlayer advancedPlayer;
AudioCache audioCache;

void initPlayer() {
  advancedPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  audioCache = AudioCache(fixedPlayer: advancedPlayer, prefix: 'sounds/');
}

Future<void> playSound(String path) async {
  await audioCache.play(path);
  return;
}
```

Here is where the methods are called:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlayer();
}

void startNewRoute() async {
    await playSound('start.mp3');
    // more code here
}
```

Here is the assets section of **pubspec.yaml**

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - images/
    - sounds/start.mp3

  fonts:
    - family: RobotoMono
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf
```

And the files are structured like this:

```
root
  lib
    [dart files]
  images
    [some images]
  sounds
    start.mp3
```

I can't find any discrepancies between what I've done here and the way the documentation of the library explains it should be used. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per by design, you should be adding "assets/" setting your **pubspec.yaml** like this:

```
assets:
    - images/
    - assets/sounds/start.mp3
```

- Audio Cache [official doc here](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/blob/master/doc/audio_cache.md)

> Don't forget to add these files to your pubspec.yaml file:
>
> flutter:   assets:
>
> - assets/explosion.mp3

someone had similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61084761/unable-to-load-asset-error-when-loading-an-mp3-file-flutter)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If I do that, it rightly tells me there is no such file. Is it imperative that I add a folder explicitly named 'assets' to my root directory? I thought that happened automatically. You can see in the callback it's attempting to get the file 'assets/sounds/start.mp3'. The 'assets' is assumed, no?

Comment: I don't quite understand why, but this worked, thanks.

Comment: Yes you would need to add the folder "assets" for the assets setting of your `pubspec.yaml`. Confusing because of the same name. Anyway, don't forget to run `flutter pub get` and do a cold restart if you currently running the code (hot reload will not load newly added assets). Thanks @vinipx!

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot use AudioCache(); with player.play('start.mp3'); This is because the method 'play' is not defined in the AudioCache class.**

Use the following class:

```
final player = AudioPlayer();
player.play(AssetSource('start.mp3'));
```

But make sure that you have added the assets for the audio track to the pubspec.yaml file:

```
 assets:
   - assets/sounds/
```

Or if the first one doesn't work try this one

```
assets:
  - assets/sounds/start.mp3
```

Comment: Appreciate the info. Haven’t used flutter since the project I was working on here, but hopefully can help someone else :)